# Are there any examples for tf.estimator.evaluate in this case?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the `estimator` APIs in TensorFlow. My purpose is as follows: During training process, after one eopch, I want to return the classification accuracy on the whole validation set. Are there any examples showing this functionality? Thanks.